# Moment fromNow() but only to a certain point

Tags: momentjs

Is there a way to use Moment's `fromNow()` function but only to a certain point? I want to setup my script so it uses `fromNow()` until it exceeds 24 hours, and then I want it to display the full timestamp. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
moment.locale('en')
moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles')

let time = moment('2017-04-12T17:37:06.886Z').fromNow()
```

I wasn't able to locate any example in the Moment docs that would allow me to easily achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Better to write your custom fromNow function.

```
function myFromNow(time) {
  let now = moment();
  return now.isSame(time, 'day') ? time.fromNow() : time.format();
}

let time1 = moment('2017-04-12T17:37:06.886Z');
let time2 = moment('2018-10-12T17:37:06.886Z');

console.log(myFromNow(time1)); //2017-04-12T19:37:06+02:00
console.log(myFromNow(time2)); //in 5 hours
```